# How add to db records with methods zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I add to db data with zend framework like:

```
       $data = array(
            'director' =>'val' ,
            'title' => 'val'
        );

        $this->insert($data);
```

Me need add to db records > 1. How did it without foreach.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Application_Model_DbTable_Wti extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

protected $_name = 'wti';

public function saveWti($json_data)
{
    //$db = $this->getAdapter()->query();
    //$query = $this->getAdapter()->query("SELECT `date` from `{$this->_name}` order by id ASC LIMIT 1");
    //$last_record = $query->fetchAll();
    //$date_in_last_record = array_shift($last_record);

    $query = $this->getAdapter()->query("SELECT count(*) FROM `{$this->_name}` ");

    $count_records = $query->fetchAll();
    $count_records = array_shift($count_records);
    $count_records = $count_records['count(*)'] > 0 ?  $count_records['count(*)']: 1 ;

    $obj_data = json_decode($json_data);
    $data_set = $obj_data->dataset;
    $data = $data_set->data;
    $data = array_reverse($data);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$this->_name}` (`date`,`open`,`high`,`low`,`settle`,`change`,`wave`,`volume`,`pdoi`,`efp`,`efs`,`block`)
            VALUES";
    $flag = false;

    for( $start = $count_records - 1; $start < count($data); $start++ )
    {
        $item = $data[$start];
        $date   = $item[0];
        $open   = empty( $item[1] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[1];
        $high   = empty( $item[2] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[2];
        $low    = empty( $item[3] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[3];
        $settle = empty( $item[4] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[4];
        $change = empty( $item[5] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[5];
        $wave   = empty( $item[6] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[6];
        $volume = empty( $item[7] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[7];
        $pdoi   = empty( $item[8] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[8];
        $efp    = empty( $item[9] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[9];
        $efs    = empty( $item[10] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[10];
        $block  = empty( $item[11] ) ? 0 : (float)$item[11];

        $sql .= "('{$date}',{$open},{$high},{$low},{$settle},{$change},{$wave},{$volume},{$pdoi},{$efp},{$efs},{$block}),";
        $flag = true;
    }

    if ( $flag )
    {
        $sql = rtrim($sql,',');

        $this->getAdapter()->query($sql);
    }

}

}
```

Only create query and use $this->getAdapter()->query($sql);